# Uploading sitemap

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to upload the sitemap of my website using google app engine launcher and submit it to google webmasters tools. However, upon uploading, I only get a blank page and webmaster gives me a 404 error. I can see that the xml file looks perfectly fine and passes validation as well before uploading. I have put it in the directory where the index.html and all other files of my website are present. Please let me know if I am missing something important with regards to xml files and GAE.

Thanks

Comment: did you try accessing the sitemap from your browser? what do you get?

Comment: @PhistucK: Thanks so much!!! I had no idea I was supposed to be declaring sitemap.xml file as static in app.yaml. I finally got it working.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any static file you serve must be declared in `app.yaml` (or a full static directory), or else it will not be served.